# Skipping a variable (year) in a ggplot x-axis using a simple function

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have this sample data:

```
df <- tibble(
  "Player" = c("Brent Seabrook", "Filip Forsberg", "Alex Ovechkin",
           "Brent Seabrook", "Filip Forsberg", "Alex Ovechkin",
           "Brent Seabrook", "Filip Forsberg", "Alex Ovechkin"),
  "Season" = c(2012, 2012, 2012,
           2013, 2013, 2013,
           2014, 2014, 2014),
  "GP" = c("82", "75", "79",
       "67", "70", "82",
       "81", "80", "82"))
```

I have a large function to pull up a plot of a player and a chosen statistic. Within that function, I have used the following code to create a scale for `"Season"`, where it will track a certain stat for a `Player` over however many seasons there were/are active:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

nhl_statistics <- function(player, statistic) {

 # Function to set YEAR scale to number of seasons played
 f <- function(k) {
  step <- k
  function(y) seq(floor(min(y)), ceiling(max(y)), by = step)
 }

 # ggplot of player and chosen statistic
 pp <- df %>% 
  group_by(Player) %>% 
  filter(Player == player) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes_string("Season", statistic),
         color = "#000000", width = .5) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = f(1)) +  # Uses the function to set Season breaks
  theme_bw() +
  coord_flip()

 return(pp)
}

# Employing the function
nhl_statistics("Brent Seabrook", "GP")
```

How can I get the plot to **skip** the 2013 season? So using the data frame above, the `ggplot` would return `Brent Seabrook` and his stats from the 2012 and 2014 season, but would **not** plot the 2013 season. It would skip from 2012 to 2014.

(`GP` = Games Played)

Comment: filter(Player == player, Season !='2013')

Comment: That successfully does not show a bar for the `2013` season, but it still leaves the `2013` label and a blank space in the plot

Comment: It would be helpful to have a reproducible example (i.e. can't run the code supplied without creating data).  There are bunch of hard coded variables that aren't supplied: e.g.  `Player`, `statistic`, and `Team`.

Comment: Fixed it, took out `Team`, and made a mini-representation of my overall function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is in your data, Season is a continuous variable (numeric) and you are hard-coding it to be broken down by 1 year at a time where you say `scale_x_continuous(breaks = f(1))`

If you want the years to be used discretely, you can mutate your data that way, like below:

```
nhl_statistics <- function(player, statistic) {

  # Function to set YEAR scale to number of seasons played
  f <- function(k) {
    step <- k
    function(y) seq(floor(min(y)), ceiling(max(y)), by = step)
  }

  # ggplot of player and chosen statistic
  pp <- df %>%
    filter(Season != 2013) %>%
    mutate(DiscreteSeason = as.factor(Season)) %>%
    group_by(Player) %>% 
    filter(Player == player) %>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_col(aes_string("DiscreteSeason", statistic),
             color = "#000000", width = .5) +
    scale_x_discrete(labels = waiver()) +  # Makes sure the labels are shown
    xlab("Season") +
    theme_bw() +
    coord_flip()

  return(pp)
}

# Employing the function
nhl_statistics("Brent Seabrook", "GP")
```